# Which class should depend on which class based on level of importance

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, modeling

I have a general question relating OOD, OOP, and Modeling and I am not sure how to ask it. The easiest way is with example. I am generaly using PHP but it can be in any other language. Let say I am a bank and I want to make a program that handles withdrawals. So I will be making 2 class Withdrawal and Account. now what is better to have the function that makes the withdrawal.
I mean:

```
$account = getAccountById(1); //account->balance = 200.00
$withdrawal = new Withdrawal(50,'USD');
$withdrawal->setAccount($account); // $withdrawal->account_id=1
$withdrawal->make(); //SQL changes account where id=1 and set balance to 150
                     //Also save a row in withdrawal tables with withdraw details
```

or

```
$account = getAccountById(1); //account->balance = 200.00
$withdrawal = new Withdrawal(50,'USD');
$account->processesWithdraw($withdrawal); //SQL changes account where id=1 and set balance to 150
                                          //Also save a row in withdrawal tables with withdraw
                                          //$withdrawal->account_id=1
```

One thing known an account is more "important" than withdrawal and can "live" without it. There may also be deposits or other actions.

There are probably many other ways to do this action. Which way do you think is the best?

I will try to give a simpler example of University Website that need to allow student to enroll to course.

So when the user click on the enroll button which will you choose? This:

```
$student = new Student('John Smith');
$course = new Course('Math');
$student->enrollToCourse($course);
```

Or this:

```
$student = new Student('John Smith');
$course = new Course('Math');
$course->addStudent($student);
```

Or maybe third option:

```
$student = new Student('John Smith');
$course = new Course('Math');
EnrollmentService::enrollStudentToCourse($student,$course);
```

Maybe all options are equally viable?

Comment: This question is too broad. Design questions like "which way do you think is the best" are not really answerable, because it's going to be opinions. The "best" depends on a whole lot of other things that you didn't specify: what other functions do you have to support? will the classes be re-used in another application?

Answer (score 2):

more likely is

```
$withdrawal = $account->withdraw(50, 'USD');
$withdrawal->completeTransaction();
```

or

```
$transfer = $account->transfer(50, 'USD', $transferToAccount);
$transfer->completeTransaction();
```

account actions should result in transactions.. the transactions should know how to persist themselves, or rollback if all updates are not successful

Comment: So are you saying that the account must create the withdraw and actually have a factory method for the withdraw transaction?

Comment: well, in accounting systems, there are typically two entries per transaction, a debit and a credit.. This would imply to me that there is a thing called a transaction, and it is created with two accounts, one for a debit and one for a credit. In reality, there is no withdrawal without a deposit (debit and credit). Withdraw would just be a transfer from a checking account to depositor liability account... when a deposit is made.. the opposite..

Answer (score 2):

for me in OOP the key point is clarity. 
I would do it like this.

```
$account = new Account(1);
$withdrawal = new Withdrawal($account, 50,'USD');
$withdrawal -> makeTransaction();
```

or

```
$account = new Account(1);
$withdrawal = new Withdrawal($account);
$withdrawal ->setAmmount(50);
$withdrawal ->setCurrency('USD');
$withdrawal -> makeTransaction();
```

I know that it's long but this approach will help you to follow "single responsibility Principe"

Comment: How would that $account->makeTransaction($withdrawal); instead of that $withdrawal -> makeTransaction(); would violate the "single responsibility Principe"?

Comment: With the `$withdrawal` performing the actual transaction, I'd say this is an example of Active Record. Imho you should be taking a look at the **Data Mapper** pattern; there should be some form of *repository* performing the transaction, with the withdrawal being an example of an entity (like a deposit), or a value object.

Comment: well $withdrawal should be inhereted from Operations and makeTransaction should be defined  in a Operations   and implemented in a Withdrawal, Deposit etc classes, in this case you will have more flexibility